# How can I replace this FBML code with iframe-ready code?

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get to work on an old Facebook App, which is a canvas facebook application and uses FBML.
Now none of the tags of FBML seems to be working, so i just want to know, is it completely removed by facebook?

If yes, how would i write the code in the for:

```
<fb:dashboard>
  <fb:action href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/index.php">Home</fb:action>
  <fb:action href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/movie.php">Movies</fb:action>
  <fb:action href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/celebrity.php">Celebrities</fb:action>
  <fb:action href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/news.php">News</fb:action>
  <fb:action href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/invite.php">Invite Friends</fb:action>
  <fb:help href="http://apps.facebook.com/ilovebolly/help.php">Help</fb:help>
</fb:dashboard>
```

Is there any method in the Javascript SDK or will I have to write pure HTML, CSS for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [roadmap](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), you can no longer create new FBML apps. However, if it's an old app you should be able to use FBML for the timebeing. According to the [FBML reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/), the individual tags aren't deprecated either. Implementing this for an iframe would involve pure HTML/CSS and Javascript if you want - there's no JS SDK method for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its really helpful. According to you FBML tags should work for the time being. In my application, <fb:tabs>, <fb:dialog id="why_profile"> and <fb:dashboard> are being used and they are not working. Is there any other reason they shouldn't work?

Comment: It's possible they were deprecated without it being documented, in my brief searching I didn't see anything about it, but they were relatively low-used tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a part of the [Facebook Roadmap for 2011](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/). you can check some tutorials for developing applications with the facebook php graph api. [Check this link.](http://wizardsoweb.com/category/facebook/)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention, the FBML still works, but you need to remove it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately for me the FBML doesn't seems to be working. With the above code links to should have come, But only text without link is what i am getting.